# Plugin with id 'android-sdk-manager' not found

Tags: android, cardslib

i want to add 
https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib

but android studio give me this error :
Error:(9, 0) Cause: cannot get property 'compileSdkVersion' on extra properties extension as it does not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The best way** to use this library with Andriod Studio is to add this dependency in your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:library:1.9.1'
}
```

If you want to clone locally you should check the top level build.gradle (in the root) inside the github repo.
It sets some variables, and you have to add these parts in your top level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.12.0'
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 19
    buildToolsVersion = "20.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Hi gabriele can you explain more i have same error too. i use android studio 1.0.1 and i use import module for import your lib.but i get same error. in my app gradle i have  (compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:library:1.9.1')

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with ChangeLog Library.(https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/changeloglib)

I thought there is no need for applying `android-sdk-manager` plugin for a library, `android library` plugin is enough. So i removed android-sdk-manager plugin from `build.gradle` left only android library plugin like below.

Change this:

```
apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

to this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

It worked without any problem in my case. I hope it will help someone else too.